# Ordering of getkeyversions output

Tags: azure-keyvault

We are using the below API to get key versions. Our assumption is it returns the list sorted by version (latest version first). Is that correct?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getkeyversions/getkeyversions

Comment: Have you tried ? what does it return ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is that correct?

Yes, based on my test, the first one is the latest version. It is ordered by created attributes.

If we want to get the latest version, we also could use Get key API

```
https://{keyvaultName}.vault.azure.net/keys/{keyName}/versions?api-version=2016-10-01
```

It will return the default **current(latest)** version of key